# React - Passing state from child to parent in drop down select

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state, react-props

I am making a basic dropdown selector. I almost had it working when I realized I was setting the state in both the parent and the child so I refactored again to try to simplify it all and put most of the responsibility in one place.

My logic is in the MyDropDown component, then I have a Header component, then the Main which should render it all.

```js
import React from 'react';

class MyDropdown extends React.Component {
  render() {
    let initialUsers = this.props.state.users;
  
    let alphabetizeUsers = initialUsers
      .sort((a, b) => {
        return a.name > b.name;
      })
      .map(obj => {
        return (
          <option key={obj.id} value={obj.name}>
            {obj.name}
          </option>
        );
      });

    return <select>{alphabetizeUsers}</select>;
  }
}

export default MyDropdown;
```

Then I have my main component where I do the api call and pass the state into the dropdown component.

```js
import React from 'react';
import MyDropdown from './MyDropdown';

class UserHeader extends React.Component {
  state = {
    users: []
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    let initialUsers = [];
    fetch('http://localhost:3000/users')
      .then(response => {
        return response.json();
      })
      .then(data => {
        this.setState({ users: data });
      });
  }

  render() {
    return <MyDropdown state={this.state} />;
  }
}

export default UserHeader;
```

And finally my Main Component, where I want to show the value from the selected dropdown menu

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './Main.css';
import MyDropdown from './components/MyDropdown';
import UserHeader from './components/UserHeader';

class Main extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <header className="App-header">
          <span className="App-title">SELECT A USER:</span>
          &nbsp; <UserHeader />
        </header>
        <p className="App-intro">
          I should get the dropdown value here: {this.state.user}
        </p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Main;
```

What I tried doing is moving the statement

```
          I should get the dropdown value here: {this.state.policies} .
```

into the UserHeader component. How do I get the value selected in the child back up to its parent?

Another thing I've tried is adding a handler to the child component

```
onChange = e => {
  this.setState({ selectedUser: e.target.value });
};
```

and add it to the select... but again not sure how to get this value up to the parent.

```
return <select onChange={this.onChange}>{alphabetizeUsers}</select>;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way to pass the value back to the parent component is through a callback.

Try defining and passing in an `onChange={this.onChange}` to your Main component like so your Main component becomes:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './Main.css';
import MyDropdown from './components/MyDropdown';
import UserHeader from './components/UserHeader';

class Main extends Component {
  this.state = {
    user: null,
  }

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.onChangeUser = this.onChangeUser.bind(this);
  }

  onChangeUser(newUser) {
    this.setState({ user: newUser });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <header className="App-header">
          <span className="App-title">SELECT A USER:</span>
          &nbsp; <UserHeader onChangeUser={this.onChangeUser} />
        </header>
        <p className="App-intro">
          I should get the dropdown value here: {this.state.user}
        </p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Main;
```

Now you are passing in a callback, you can do the same thing with your `UserHeader` component.

```js
import React from 'react';
import MyDropdown from './MyDropdown';

class UserHeader extends React.Component {
  state = {
    users: []
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    let initialUsers = [];
    fetch('http://localhost:3000/users')
      .then(response => {
        return response.json();
      })
      .then(data => {
        this.setState({ users: data });
      });
  }

  render() {
    return <MyDropdown state={this.state} onChange={this.props.onChangeUser} />;
  }
}

export default UserHeader;
```

And finally, you can now attach this callback to your `<select>` element.

```js
import React from 'react';

class MyDropdown extends React.Component {
  render() {
    let initialUsers = this.props.state.users;
  
    let alphabetizeUsers = initialUsers
      .sort((a, b) => {
        return a.name > b.name;
      })
      .map(obj => {
        return (
          <option key={obj.id} value={obj.name}>
            {obj.name}
          </option>
        );
      });

    return <select onChange={(ev) => this.props.onChange(ev.target.value)}>{alphabetizeUsers}</select>;
  }
}

export default MyDropdown;
```

By defining the onChange on your `select` element like this, `onChange={(ev) => this.props.onChange(ev.target.value)}`, you can return the value to the main component and use it in your state.

Comment: This worked. Just had to change "I should get the dropdown value here: {this.state.user}" to {this.state.selectedUser}. One more thing... do you know how to set the default? It is working when I click on something from the dropdown but not when it loads initially.

Comment: Thanks, I've made the edit. You want to pass the `defaultValue` to your `<select>` so that `<select sefaultValue={this.props.user}>`. You should pass this down from your main component or the you could have a default passed down from the `MyDropdown` component.

Comment: I can't seem to get it working... so in MyDropdown I have <select
        defaultValue={this.props.policy}  > then in UserHeader<PolicyDropdown
        defaultValue={this.props.policy}
      /> and then the same in Main<PolicyHeader
              onChangePolicy={this.onChangePolicy}
              defaultValue={this.props.policy}
            /> But this can't be right...

Comment: Remember that `defaultValue` is a special property for html elements like `<select>`, when you add a default value like `<select defaultValue={this.props.policy}>` on **PolicyHeader**, you must pass the correctly named prop down as well so `<PolicyDropdown policy={this.props.policy}>` and so on. If you have your 'policy' in state at the top, keep passing it down to the component via props with the correct name.

Comment: Got it. So far I have in the Parent: <UserHeader onChangeUser={this.onChangeUser} user={this.state.selectedUser} /> then in the intermediate component UserHeader <UserDropdown
        user={this.props.user}
        state={this.state}
        onChange={this.props.onChangeUser}
      />  ); and finally in the dropdown component         defaultValue={this.props.user}